# Share Data Through Service in ASP.NET Blazor (Client Side)

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.0, blazor-client-side

I use to have a common service in MVC Application , register it as Transient service and access its value across whole application without any issue .

I tried to implement same mechanism inside my client side blazor app

First created a class AppState

```
public class AppState
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
}
```

registered as a service

```
services.AddSingleton<AppState, AppState>();
```

Used in Blazor Component Index Component

```
public class IndexComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    HttpClient Http { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public AppState AppState { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AppState = await Http.GetJsonAsync<AppState>(ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json"));
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Tried to print base url in index.razor file

```
@page "/"
@inherits IndexComponent

<p>@AppState.BaseUrl</p>
```

Till Here its fine , now as it contain base url so i wanted to access it in another component

```
public class MiniCartComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    public AppState AppState { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Here it is empty , i dont know why

I tried to print it in razor file

```
@inherits MiniCartComponent
<p>@AppState.BaseUrl</p>
```

Here it is empty , it is registered as a service to share data across components , should not it have value across the app once it is set ??

Comment: Change  **AppState = await Http.GetJsonAsync<AppState>(ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json"));** to **var appState = await Http.GetJsonAsync<AppState>(ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json")); AppState.BaseUrl = appState.BaseUrl;**

Comment: Ok , it worked , what is the concept behind it . In future there will be many keys in json files , and i have to set them one by one in this way

Comment: Just modify AppState, don't set it by other value. If has many field, just wrap it to other class.

Comment: Ok , but how it is working after AppState.BaseUrl = appState.BaseUrl; , Can you clarify it

Comment: You register AppState as singleton, I called it instance A, when you inject to your component it still instance A and you set AppState in you component with result from API it will be instance B, no effect to instance A.

Answer (score 4):

1st you register a singleton instance

```
services.AddSingleton<AppState, AppState>();
```

this look a bit weird to me. IMHO, it should be

```
services.AddSingleton<IAppState, AppState>();
```

or

```
services.AddSingleton<AppState>();
```

But that's not the probleme.

You inject this service in a component whicht is great

```cs
[Inject]
public AppState AppState { get; set; }
```

And you erase this component instance with a new one get from a web api

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    AppState = await Http.GetJsonAsync<AppState>(ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json"));
    await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Their again the code is weird, it should be

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    AppState = await Http.GetJsonAsync<AppState>(ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json"));
}
```

But that doesn't reset the singleton instance you inject in your second component. That just replace the instance in your 1st component.

- You should register your service with

```
services.AddSingleton<AppState>(provider =>
{
    var http = provider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
    return http.GetJsonAsync<AppState>(ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json")).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
});
```

This way you make just one call to *appsettings.json* during the app life.

- And remove `OnInitializedAsync` code.

## Async

But actually, the best way to achieve that is to register a `Task` returning your settings

```cs
services.AddSingleton(provider =>
{
    var http = provider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
    return http.GetJsonAsync<AppState>("appsettings.json");
});
```

You can inject it in your components with

```cs
[Inject]
public Task<AppState> AppStateAsync { get; set; }

public AppState AppState { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    AppState = await AppStateAsync;
}
```

And use it with

```html
@page "/"
@inherits IndexComponent

<p>@AppState.BaseUrl</p>
```

Comment: If i put my code inside startup.cs , the app does not start up , just a white blank page saying Loading..... forever , My Update Code is services.AddSingleton<IAppConfig,AppConfig>(provider =>
            {
                var http = provider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
                return http.GetJsonAsync<AppConfig>(ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            });

Comment: Try with `http.GetJsonAsync<AppConfig>(ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json")).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: What is `ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json")` ?

Comment: There is a folder under wwwroot named by ConfigFiles , under there appsetting.json . ConfigFiles.GetPath("appsettings.json") just do return Path.Combine("ConfigFiles", "appsetting.json");

Comment: Path.Combine() is for filenames. Client-side you only have URLs. It's a small wonder it works.

Comment: @HenkHolterman , After removing Path.Combine and supplying plain URL as "ConfigFiles/appsettings.json" the result is same , looks like from startuhiship.cs this path is not found and thus the blank white page ....

Comment: @HenkHolterman even if i introduce another layer (as service , like we have in angular) to get info from json through httpcall , its not accessible . Looks like wwwroot folder url is accessible only from razor page or its Basecomponent file

Comment: @HenkHolterman Just to add little info , the error for blank white page  is - Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded