# Custom IConfiguration Service in Client SIde Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0, blazor-client-side

I am trying to have some basic configuration from json file to a singleton service inside my client side blazor application at the start up.

Below is my code setup

AppConfig and IAppConfig files

```
interface IAppConfig
{
    string BaseUrl { get; set; }

    string Source { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class AppConfig : IAppConfig
{
  public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
  public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

Than a json file by the name of environment.json inside wwwroot as wwwroot/ConfigFiles/environment.json

Than a service to read this file

```
interface ISharedServices
{
  Task<AppConfig> GetConfigurationAsync();
}
```

and

```
public class SharedServices : ISharedServices
{
    private HttpClient Http { get; set; }

    public SharedServices(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        Http = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<AppConfig> GetConfigurationAsync()
    {
        return await Http.GetJsonAsync<AppConfig>("ConfigFiles/environment.json");
    }
}
```

Now i am calling it into my component which load first

```
public class IndexComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    internal IAppConfig AppConfig { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    internal ISharedServices sharedServices { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var appconfig = await sharedServices.GetConfigurationAsync();
        AppConfig = appconfig;
    }
}
```

All this works fine , but i want to have this configuration ready at the time of application load in browser , so as suggested by "auga from mars" in my other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128731/share-data-through-service-in-asp-net-blazor-client-side/) i tried below code inside startup.cs at the moment i add IAppConfig as singleton service

```
services.AddSingleton<IAppConfig, AppConfig>(provider =>
 {
   var http = provider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
   return http.GetJsonAsync<AppConfig>("ConfigFiles/environment.json").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  });
```

But , buy using this code the blazor app never start up , all it show a blank white page with text Loading.... , not even any error but in every 5 min pop up show - page taking too much time to load with two option of wait and close .

If i change this code a bit from

```
return http.GetJsonAsync<AppConfig>("ConfigFiles/environment.json").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

to

```
return http.GetJsonAsync<AppConfig>("ConfigFiles/environment.json").Result;
```

Than it say - "Maximum call stack size exceed"

How to have configuration ready at startup ??

**Update 1:**

A little Update

in Basecomponent file , code is

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var appconfig = await sharedServices.GetConfigurationAsync();
        AppConfig.BaseUrl = appconfig.BaseUrl;
        AppConfig.Source = appconfig.Source;
    }
```

I have to set every property one by one manually , need to get rid of this too

Comment: Using .Result is indeed not the right way.

Comment: What exactly is "at the time of application load in browser" ?  Whay is missing or failing now?  Do you need the config values in startup?

Comment: By placing it in the BaseComponent, the file will be read each time any derived compponent is shown.  Is that the intention?

Comment: @HenkHolterman , need the config values at startup  ? - Yes , It should not read file again and again , it should read set IAppConfig in startup.cs

Comment: Also i added IsFixed="true" as it will never change . After adding IsFixed="true" the configuration is available on components which comes after Index.razor , for Index.razor (first page) it stopped showing config information , removed IsFixed than info will be available for index.razor also

Comment: Since blazor web assembly will initialize on browser, your config file would read once per user.